# Python code disappears from html code

Tags: html, html-escape-characters

```
particleShape1.incandescencePP=<<rand(0.8.1),rand(0,0.5),rand(0,0.5);  #rands are r,g,b, 1=100%.
```

I wanted the above line to read as is in a html document. Right now without any tags part of it disappears completely. Any ideas how I can get this to stay visible with the formatting I have on the document? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `pre` tags:

`<pre> particleShape1.incandescencePP=<<rand(0.8.1),rand(0,0.5),rand(0,0.5);  #rands are r,g,b, 1=100%. </pre>`

...replacing any `<` with `&lt;` because they are still parsed with pre tags:

`<pre> particleShape1.incandescencePP=&lt;&lt;rand(0.8.1),rand(0,0.5),rand(0,0.5);  #rands are r,g,b, 1=100%. </pre>`

http://jsfiddle.net/JDQRG/

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of `pre` tag. [docs](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre&ei=mohnU4_QE4iXuATs54GgAg&usg=AFQjCNGRhpxakqXTKDXjjRsKZp8cdOQq7A&sig2=UwV8Cq7tBoa4emnzj2-VNg&bvm=bv.65788261,d.c2E&cad=rja)

It is used to show code inside html document.